# AzurePS System capability is not available on a newly installed vsts-agent

Tags: azure-devops

I have successfully installed a new VSTS agent on a new Azure VM - Windows Server 2012 R2 (64bit).  When I am try to execute any pipelines containing azure powershell tasks on the new vsts agent, I get an error message :-

Error message 'No agent found in pool BuildAgent2 which satisfies the specified demands:azureps Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.119.1'

Is there any way to add AzurePS as a system capability ? 
Please advise on the steps to do this - thanks.

Comment: You may need to install all kinds of 3rd party tools and then restart the agent for it to detect the capability. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-2.8.0

Comment: I would recommend looking at Microsoft's packer images for their Windows build machines as a starting point: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation

Answer (score 7):

> AzurePS System capability is not available on a newly installed vsts-agent

Agree with jessehouwing.

If you want to enable AzurePS System capability, you could install the `PowerShell 5.1` or higher on Windows, or `PowerShell Core 6.x` and later on all platforms, then install/update the Azure PowerShell module on the Azure VM:

[Install the Azure PowerShell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-2.8.0)

But the error you got should more related to the demands you set on the option tab of your build :

[image]

Check the agent version you have installed, make sure you set the correct version, or you can try to remove that demands to check if you still have this issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: many thanks for all your suggestions - it looks like the Azure VM has an older version of Powershell, so have got PowerShell 6.1.3 installed and will try and uninstall/re-install the agent.

Comment: @dipika-bg, hi, friend. How the things going now? Does the error message continue to bother you now after you tried the solution mentioned above? If still has any other issue, feel free to leave comment here. Thus we could continue to help you.

Comment: it worked for me, but I had to add a user-defined-capability to my agent. I set azureps
 to true.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error using the AzureFileCopy@4 task in a self-hosted agent, but I solved it by installing the az module https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az

`Install-Module -Name Az`