# Azure DevOps Release Pipeline failing

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Opened this query in MS Developer Community Forum / Azure DevOps issue

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/No-agent-found-in-pool-Default-which-sat/10141890?space=21&q=gtversion&entry=problem

Trying to work out why the "Pipeline" runs successfully with my self-hosted docker agent but the "Release Pipeline" fails, it's asking for a version way under the version of the agent I am running

“No agent found in pool Default which satisfies the specified demands: azureps, Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.144.0”

Any given help will be very much appreciated

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58416327/azureps-system-capability-is-not-available-on-a-newly-installed-vsts-agent. `-gtVersion 2.144.0` means it's looking for agent version > 2.144.0, which should be fine.

Comment: @riQQ Hi there, thanks for replying, I had seen that question before but the steps are not related the agent got installed PowerShell, az and more, pipelines run well and the artefact is crated is the release pipeline that for some reason fails not even trying to run with this annoying error

Answer (score 0):

Compromised installing the PS AzureRM module necessary for the release pipeline tasks to run, and added two user-defined capabilities to the agent to overcome the initial error

Documented the "solution" here

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/No-agent-found-in-pool-Default-which-sat/10141890